# Windows path problems running bat file through launchy

Tags: windows-10, path, launchy

I'm trying to run a batch file from launchy 2.5.0 [(website)](https://www.launchy.net/) in Win 10 1809

```
cd
path
where ssh.exe
ssh.exe 
pause
```

When I try to run it from launchy

```
E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>cd
E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>path
PATH=C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Crucial\Crucial Storage Executive;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\andy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>where ssh.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>ssh.exe
'ssh.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

running it from cmd gives

```
E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>cd
E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>path
PATH=C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Crucial\Crucial Storage Executive;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\andy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>where ssh.exe
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>ssh.exe
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]

E:\scripts\machine-config\launchy-shortcuts-windows\power>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

As the paths look the same, I'm guessing it's some permissions issue?

The same behaviour happens whether I run launchy.exe from shell:startup, as my user or right click and run as admin